# How can I open windows qt project on ubuntu? - No rule to make target error

Tags: qt, ubuntu

I have been trying to open a Qt project on ubuntu. It works on windows 10 but in ubuntu 16.04 LTS it shows

'No rule to make target 'QVideoWidget.h', needed by 'ui_mainwindow.h'. Stop.'

I have tried Clean and also deleting QWidget which was promoted to QVideoWidget, but the error remains.
How can I fix this error?

Comment: clean the build folder

Comment: but only build, release folder exists..no build folder

Comment: I also unchecked shadow build option.